# Java Scanner trouble

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner

Recently I started learning Java. Probably this is a stupid question: using 'p' character as delimiter for my Scanner I expect the output will be

**42**

**17**

**Hello World**

while it is

**42**

**17**

**pHello World**

Delimiter may be excluded from the tokens of the Scanner, so why also 'p' char is printed in the last line?

'''

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "42p17pHello World";
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(s);
    scan.useDelimiter("p");
    System.out.println(scan.nextInt());
    System.out.println(scan.nextInt());
    System.out.println(scan.nextLine());
    scan.close();
}
```

'''

Answer (score 1):

Calling `nextLine()` reads the next line from the scanner and does not seem to stop at the delimiter. Replace the `nextLine()` call with `next()`.